# How can I fix an illegal start of an expression?

Tags: java, arrays, shoutcast

The assignment deals with create a main class and then two other classes for a canned statement and a random statement.  The canned statement prints whatever canned responses.  That portion works just fine.  However my random portion works on its own but in this scenario it doesn't.  I'm missing some statement that associates it to the right class.

This is the main class:

```
package it511_module8_milestone4;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class IT511_Module8_Milestone4 {


    //Allow for User Input
    int UserInput;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Implement shoutOutCannedMessage
    public void shoutOutCannedMessage(String[] myArray) {
        for (int index = 0; index <= 3; index++) {

            //Print out the Array Container
            System.out.print(myArray[index] + "\n");
        }
    }
    public void shoutOutRandomMessage(String[] Subject, String[] Verb, 
            String[] Adjective, String[] Object, String[] Adverb) {

        //Random number generator 
        int num0 = [int] (Math.random()*6);  ***This is the issue***
        int num1 = (int) (Math.random()*3);
        int num2 = (int) (Math.random()*3);
        int num3 = (int) (Math.random()*3);
        int num4 = (int) (Math.random()*3); 

        {
            //Print Random Message
            System.out.println(Subject[num0]+Verb[num1]+Adjective[num2]+
                Object[num3]+Adverb[num4]);  
            }

        }
}
```

This is the public class:

```
public class RandomMessage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //String of six names to be stored in the Array
        String []Subject;
        Subject = new String[6];

        //Subject Array Container
        Subject[0] = ("Ken");  
        Subject[1] = ("Erica");
        Subject[2] = ("Nathan");
        Subject[3] = ("Alana");
        Subject[4] = ("Nolan");
        Subject[5] = ("Ethan");

        //Verb Array 
        String []Verb;
        Verb = new String[3];

        //Verb Array Container
        Verb[0] = (" threw ");
        Verb[1] = (" kicked ");
        Verb[2] = (" caught ");

        //Adjective Array Container
        String []Adjective;
        Adjective = new String[3];

        //Adjective Array Container
        Adjective[0] = ("the red");
        Adjective[1] = ("the blue");
        Adjective[2] = ("the white");

        //Object Array Container
        String []Object;
        Object = new String[3];

        //Object Array Container
        Object[0] = (" football ");
        Object[1] = (" soccer ball ");
        Object[2] = (" baseball ");

        //Adverb Array Container
        String []Adverb;
        Adverb = new String[3];

        //Verb Array Container
        Adverb[0] = ("hard.");
        Adverb[1] = ("far.");
        Adverb[2] = ("sadly.");

        String list = new RandomMessage().shoutOutRandomMessage(Subject, Verb,
                Adjective, Object, Adverb);
    }

    public String shoutOutRandomMessage(String[] Subject, String[] Verb,
               String[] Adjective, String[] Object, String[] Adverb) {

        //Random number generator 
        int num0 = (int) (Math.random()*6);
        int num1 = (int) (Math.random()*3);
        int num2 = (int) (Math.random()*3);
        int num3 = (int) (Math.random()*3);
        int num4 = (int) (Math.random()*3);        

        System.out.println(Subject[num0]+Verb[num1]+Adjective[num2]+
                Object[num3]+Adverb[num4]);


        //Return statement
        String message = ("Great Choice!");
        return message;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're using square brackets `[]` instead of parentheses `()`.

Answer (score 2):

you are casting double to int , and format of casting is using `()` and add class or primitive type you want to cast inside, so replace `[]` by `()`.

```
 int num0 = (int) (Math.random()*6);
```